# get date from dateTime in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to extract date without time from a single value from array result thaht I got.

I tried using array_slice but it didn't work.

My code..

```
    $dateRows = $this->get('app')->getDates();
    $dateRow = json_decode(json_encode($dateRows[0], true));

    dump($dateRow[0]);die;
```

And I got result..

> "2014-01-01 00:00:00"

And I want it to return just

> "2014-01-01"

Comment: Substring 10 characters from `$dateRow[0]`. Meaning `echo substr($dateRow[0], 0,10);`

Comment: Perhaps try using a DateTime and get your value specifying the format.

Comment: What's the point of json encoding and json decoding the same variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very Simple, just use `date_create()` on your date & then format it using `date_format()` as follows -

```
$date = date_create("2014-01-01 00:00:00");
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
```

So, in your case, it would be something like -

```
$date1 = date_create($dateRows[0]);
echo date_format($date1,"Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use strtotime function as well for getting formatted data

```
$a = "2014-01-01 00:00:00";

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a));
```

Comment: strtotime can cost you problems. I'd suggest using DateTime class and createFromFormat method. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php